# Why is the type char?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why is the type of employees[0].position[5] a char instead of a string? I got this wrong on a test, and I can't figure out why. Appreciate your help.

```
struct Name
    {
    string firstName;
    char middleInitial;
    string lastName;
    };
    class EmployeeInfo
    {
    Name name;
    int age;
    int id;
    string position;
    public:
    Name getName() { return name; }
    };
    EmployeeInfo employees[100];
```

Comment: If `position` was a string, and `position[5]` was a string, then what would stop you doing `position[5][1][7][20][8]` or something like that? (And if that's allowed: what the heck would it do?)

Comment: @immibis, easy, get the 8th character of the 20th string of the 4th dimension of the 7th string of the 3rd dimension of the 1st string of the second dimension of the 5th string of the 1st dimension. :)

Comment: What happens if there are more than 100 employees? Why isn't getName const and returning a const reference? Whoever wrote this test isn't a C++ expert.

Comment: Please do not deface your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what IS a string? In C, and (with a little bit of abstraction), C++, it's a character array `char[]` (null terminated, ofc). So when you have a string `position` and you index into it with the overloaded `operator []` like this: `position[5]` that means you are going into the array and grabbing the <strike>fifth</strike> sixth element, which in the case of a string is a character. Or `char`. I'd highly suggest reviewing your string material, since it **should** have beaten that into any coding students head in week 2 or 3.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I didn't look at it closely enough. I give up too easily :/

Comment: Just remember, if you give up, they win. *Illegitimi non carborundum*

Comment: Also remember if coding was easy, there wouldn't be a stackoverflow.

Comment: Note that `position[5]` grabs the *sixth* character, not the fifth, because indices start at 0. (Off-topic: strangely, lots of people insist that it would be totally insane to have them start at 1)

Comment: @BenjaminErichsen: See? And I'm an idiot. Everyone wins.

Comment: More precisely, the type `std::string` is a *class* type, not an array, but it effectively represents an array of `char`. It has an overloaded `operator []` that takes an integral index and yields a `char` value.

Comment: And the teacher becomes the student. In my defense, I did say "with a little abstraction". Still, have an upvote for putting into words what I couldn't. :)